# Progress Monitor Implementation in Java

Tags: java, progress-bar, dialog

I want to show the progress of my program process which using progress monitor in java. i've put this code below as progress monitor in my new frame.

```
package eksim.view;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.ProgressMonitor;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;


public class ProgBar extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame implements ActionListener {

    static ProgressMonitor pbar;
    static int counter = 0;

    /**
     * Creates new form ProgBar
     */
    public ProgBar() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void ProgressMonitorExample() {
    super("Progress Monitor Demo");
    setSize(250, 100);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    pbar = new ProgressMonitor(null, "Monitoring Progress",
        "Initializing . . .", 0, 100);

    // Fire a timer every once in a while to update the progress.
    Timer timer = new Timer(500, this);
    timer.start();
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    UIManager.put("ProgressMonitor.progressText", "This is progress?");
    UIManager.put("OptionPane.cancelButtonText", "Go Away");
    ProgressMonitorExample();
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // Invoked by the timer every half second. Simply place
    // the progress monitor update on the event queue.
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Update());
  }

  class Update implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
      if (pbar.isCanceled()) {
        pbar.close();
        System.exit(1);
      }
      pbar.setProgress(counter);
      pbar.setNote("Operation is " + counter + "% complete");
      counter += 2;
    }
  }


    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jProgressBar1 = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();

        setClosable(true);
        setIconifiable(true);
        setMaximizable(true);
        setTitle("Progress Monitor");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                .addComponent(jProgressBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 335, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(28, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(66, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jProgressBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(48, 48, 48))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JProgressBar jProgressBar1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

But, it didn't show anything as it works. Could anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: The code won't compile. You call `ProgressMonitorExample()` from a static context.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from a few compilation problems in your code (detailed below), it works fine here. The progress bar updates as expected here.

First, move the code from `public void ProgressMonitorExample()` to the constructor, and remove that method. The constructor should look like this:

```
    public ProgBar() {
        super("Progress Monitor Demo");
        initComponents();
    setSize(250, 100);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    pbar = new ProgressMonitor(null, "Monitoring Progress",
        "Initializing . . .", 0, 100);

    // Fire a timer every once in a while to update the progress.
    Timer timer = new Timer(500, this);
    timer.start();
    setVisible(true);
  }
```

Second, since `public void ProgressMonitorExample()` is now gone, properly create a new ProgBar object instead:

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    UIManager.put("ProgressMonitor.progressText", "This is progress?");
    UIManager.put("OptionPane.cancelButtonText", "Go Away");
    ProgBar pb = new ProgBar();
  }
```

Comment: i take your instruction but i get confused. When could i call this ProgBar? Must i call it when i click button from another view of the project?